# Essential singularity

Tags: cv.complex-variables, singularity-theory, analytic-functions

In shaum's outline complex analysis,definition of essential point is:
An isolated singularity that is not pole or removable singularity is called essential singularity
Now in the same book there is an excercise that;
Locate and name the singularity of sec(1/z)........it says that z=0 is essential singularity...but also it is non isolated...
I wonder that how can an essential singularity be a non isolated as according to definition essential singularity is isolated,I know that singularity z=0 is non isolated,but from my point of view it should not be essential as it not isolated

Answer (score 5):

There are two points of view here, which are frequently confused in textbooks.

1. The name "essential singularity" is used only for analytic functions (whose image is in C), with isolated singularities. Then $\sec(1/z)$ has a non-isolated singularity at 0.
2. In another context one considers meromorphic functions (as holomorphic maps to
   the Riemann sphere). From this point of view, poles are not singularities at all,
   and $\sec(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $0$.

Text books usually gloss over this fine distinction. As well as over the question
whether "removable singularities" are singularities or not. For example,
what is the singularity of $$\frac{\sin(2/z)}{\sin(1/z)}=2\cos(1/z)$$ at zero?
Is it essential, or non-isolated (limit of removable singularities)?

Similar confusion applies to the expression "there exists a limit". The authors frequently forget to specify where this limit is supposed to be.
If the functions are supposed to map the domain into $C$ then he limit at a pole does not exist. If they are considered as maps to the Riemann sphere, it exists, and the difference between a pole and "removable singularity" disappears.